# How to know whether a email address exists on Elasticsearch?

Tags: api, elasticsearch, postman

So I have added some data (email address with name) on elasticsearch . Now want to verify a particular email address is exists or not .

**Below is the code which I have Executed via Postman :**

```
**URL :** localhost:9200/demo1/demo_emails/_bulk (Put request)

**Raw Data (json) :** 
{ "create" : { "_index" : "demo1", "_type" : "Supp_emails", "_id" : "2" } }
{ "name" : "x1", "email": "x1@r.com" }
{ "create" : { "_index" : "demo1", "_type" : "Supp_emails", "_id" : "3" } }
{ "name" : "x2", "email": "x2@r.com" }
```

You can see "demo1" is the Index & "demo_emails" is the field type . And I have added two email address on that index.
Now want to verify whether 'x1@r.com' is exist or not ?

I have tried the below query, but its showing all details instead of one email

```
**URL :** localhost:9200/demo1/Supp_emails/_search?q=email:x1@r.com (Get request)

**Output :**
{
"took": 2,
"timed_out": false,
"_shards": {
    "total": 3,
    "successful": 3,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
},
"hits": {
    "total": 2,
    "max_score": 0.87546873,
    "hits": [
        {
            "_index": "demo1",
            "_type": "demo_emails",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 0.87546873,
            "_source": {
                "name": "x1",
                "email": "x1@r.com"
            }
        },
        {
            "_index": "demo1",
            "_type": "demo_emails",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 0.87546873,
            "_source": {
                "name": "x2",
                "email": "x2@r.com"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you search for *email:x1@r.com* the tokenizer breaks up the string into tokens. These tokens depend on which analyzer and tokenizer you've used.

I'm assuming you didn't do any fancy analysis, so these tokens would be :
GET index/_analyze

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "x1",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "r.com",
      "start_offset": 3,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

If you take a look at the documentation of [query_string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html) you'll find that default operator is OR
So your query actually looks for *x1 OR r.com*, this is why both of these documents return.

You can see this by adding the parameter http://elastic...?q=...**&explain=true**.

How do you solve this issue? Use a different operator. Just change the default operator to AND, d http://elastic...?q=...&**default_operator=true**

Useful links:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-uri-request.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.2/indices-analyze.html

Comment: So I have change the default_operator on parameter section from 'true' to 'AND' and it works. Very clear explanation for a beginner like me . Thank you very much . Will disturb you again when find another problem

Comment: @Rahul_Rdr If it helps \feel free to upvote and accept the answer

Comment: You generally want to use a [keyword](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) for fields like that — you are only interested in the exact match. You might want to combine this with a [lowercase normalizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-normalizers.html).

Comment: @xeraa Depends on your usecase, if you don't care about the individual parts, keyword works best, however, you might want to search by domain, user.etc

Comment: The original question was: "a particular email address is exists or not" — this should be a keyword.

Comment: @xeraa That's a guess on your part. How do you know what use cases OP has?

Comment: @aclokay Need help again , want to search multiple email on a single request . means I want to verify x1@r.com,x2@r.com,x10@r.com are exists or not !  what will be the json then ?

Comment: @Rahul_Rdr All of them? just one of them? You want to find subset of the addresses that exist? Open a new question with details

Comment: Need to check all of them in a single request

Comment: Use bool query, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html